# What happened between Monster Girl and Robot?

Tags: comics, robert-kirkman, invincible

In Robert Kirkman's Invincible universe, the characters Robot (Rex) and Monster Girl (Amanda) go through a portal to the Flaxan's dimension during a battle (in issue 71, if I recall correctly).  Before entering the portal they were extremely close - they were around the same age, Robot helped keep Monster Girl from aging (creating a belt and a refined version of Black Samson's suit), and were just very close emotionally.

Sometime later (around issue 81-82, I think?) they return, having aged significantly.  At this point they are emotionally distant, and Robot is very hurt by actions Monster Girl took in the Flaxan dimension.

What happened to cause the rift between them, and in what issue of what series did it occur?

Comment: Monster Girl and Robot finally return from the Flaxan dimension in Guarding the Globe 6, but there's really no explanation provided as to what exactly happened.

Comment: In the letters page of Invincible #91, Kirkman said this will be explained in #92. So, not long left!

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened? Self-answering is [built into the UI](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) now, after all :)

Comment: @Tacroy The story arc began in #92, but it's still going. They've been very vague, but as soon as it's made clear, I'll answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the story arc that starts in issues #92 - #95 detail how Monster Girl(Amanda) and Robot(Rex) traveled to the Flaxan homeworld where they used their newfound immortality to spend a nearly a century plotting a rebellion to free the planet's offworld slaves. After succeeding, Rex became supreme ruler and embarked on an ambitious plan of reconstruction. At the same time, he and Amanda became lovers.

Over the next 700(ish) years, Rex became increasingly despotic as the economy faltered (due to a lack of offworld labour and resources) and he was forced to crack down on the historical rulers, the Zaxals:

[image]

When the Zaxal royal family rebelled, Amanda supported them in deposing him.

[image]

And on top of that political betrayal, she also embarked on a lesbian romance with one of the Zaxal princesses.

[image]

And after nearly a millennium away from Earth, the two of them finally returned through the portal older, wiser and **deeply embittered** about each other.

[image]

Comment: @Raj - Their estrangement happened well before he found out.